How do I allow 3D-Secure iframe popups in iOS in cordova
My Cordova app is blocking iframes used by 3D-secure payments.
I don't know the domains of the iframes, I guess they could change per bank.
Do I remove the Content-Security-Policy tag from the main page? or can I change it somehow to allow any domain in an iframe?
Thanks :)

add frame-src *; to your CSP
